# How to call variable by string?

Tags: javascript

I want to create something like php associative array in JavaScript. I know there are objects

```
var obj = 
{
    property1: "value1" ,
    ...
};
```

In this case I have to call `obj.property1`
But while script is running I get string "property1", so I would like to call it like `obj."property1"`, but I don't know what exactly should write.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Comment: Use `obj['property1']`

Comment: A couple of side notes on terminology (in order to be helpful, not snarky): It's a "property," not a "variable." You don't "call" variables (or properties), you "use" them or "reference" them or "get" values from them or "assign" values to them, etc. You "call" functions and methods and constructors (that is, things that **do** things).